# Simple List of Links in Django Blog

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have a django blog and am creating a list of links to other blogs. Created a model class "Friend".

In my models.py file.

> class Friend(models.Model):
>
> ```
>   title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
>   link = models.URLField(max_length=60)
>
>   def __unicode__(self):
>       return self.title
> ```

In my views file, I included friends = Friend.objects.all() and friends=friend in render().
However, the list of blog links still does not appear on my main home page. Can someone point out to me what I have done incorrectly? Thank you.

```
def home(request):
    friends = Friend.objects.all()
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-pub_date")
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 5)

    try: 
        page = int(request.GET.get("page", 1))
    except ValueError: page = 1

    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except (InvalidPage, EmptyPage):
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_page)

    return render(request, "home.html",
                            dict(posts=posts, friends=friends, user=request.user))
```

In my home.html file,

```
<div id="box">
    <font class="header">ROTATING FAVES</font>
    {% for friend in friends.object_list %}      
     <div class="textwidget">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="{{ friend.link }}" target="_blank">{{ friend.title }}</a><br /></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

Comment: can you show the code of your template?

Comment: yup i just included it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sending your friends to your template, now you have to render it.

You can check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/).

It should be something like this in your html:

```
{% for friend in friends %}
    <a href="{{ friend.link }}">{{ friend.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: actually i did include the for loop and variable friend in my home.html. but the list did not appear. let me update my question.

Comment: Try with friends instead of friends.object_list

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/generic-views/ ----> maybe it's only for generic views?

Comment: Thats for generics views in django 1.3. If you are starting a new project make sure to use the latest django version (1.7 at this moment). If you want to use generic views, use updated documentation (bottom right and select 1.7). Generic views have changed a lot since 1.3.

Comment: i see. thank you. btw, do you of good documentation for generic views, class based views? i can't find any good tutorials that explain it... much appreciated!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63496/discussion-between-cdvv7788-and-codemax).